# Select the theme from a telerik combobox MVC/ASP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik, telerik-mvc

I want to implement a feature similar to the telerik theme feature available on their demo site. (I have a fully licenced copy of their controls), but I cant find any info on how to do this.

I have an MVC application, and in the _Layout.cshtml (which has no controller that I know of (i hope I am wrong)) I am trying to add a combo box populated with a list of available styles like this:

```
    <section id="Login">
        @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
           {
                <section id="loginImage">
                    <img src="../../Content/Images/BlankPerson.jpg" />
                </section>
                <section id="loginText">
                    [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]
                    <br />
                    @User.Identity.Name!

                    @(
                        /* TELERIK COMBOBOX */

                        Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
                        .Name("cbxTheme")
                        .Placeholder("Select Theme...")
                        .SelectedIndex(0)
                        .ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("cbxTheme_onChange"))
                        //.BindTo((IEnumerable<DropDownItem>)ViewData["Files"])
                        .Items(item =>
                            {
                                item.Add().Text("black");
                                item.Add().Text("common");
                                item.Add().Text("default");
                                item.Add().Text("forest");
                                item.Add().Text("hay");
                                item.Add().Text("metro");
                                item.Add().Text("office2007");
                                item.Add().Text("office2010black");
                                item.Add().Text("office2010blue");
                                item.Add().Text("office2010silver");
                                item.Add().Text("outlook");
                                item.Add().Text("rtl");
                                item.Add().Text("simple");
                                item.Add().Text("sitefinity");
                                item.Add().Text("sunset");
                                item.Add().Text("telerik");
                                item.Add().Text("transparent");
                                item.Add().Text("vista");
                                item.Add().Text("web20");
                                item.Add().Text("webblue");
                                item.Add().Text("windows7");
                            })
                    )
                </section>                  
           }
    </section>
```

As directed by Telerik. We must include the following lines at the start and end of our view as follows:

```
<head>
@(

  Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar()
                .DefaultGroup(group => group
                .Add("telerik.common.css")
                .Add("telerik.black.css").Combined(true).Compress(true)
                .Add("telerik." +   + ".css", ).Combined(true).Compress(true)
                //.Add("telerik." + Html.GetCurrentTheme() + ".css").Combined(true).Compress(true)


                //"javascript:cbxTheme_onChange()"
                ))

</head>

.
.
.
.


<body>
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(true).Compress(true)))
</body>
```

Also I have a little bit of JQuery which works but I cant access it the way I need to and this is where my problem is:

```
<script>
    function cbxTheme_onChange()
    {
        var selectedItemText = $("#cbxTheme").data("tComboBox").text();
        var selectedItemValue = $("#cbxTheme").data("tComboBox").value();
        alert(selectedItemValue);

        return selectedItemText;
    }

</script>
```

The function above actually does work and pops a message up with the selected item. No problem there.

The problem I am having is with this line of code in the head section as shown above:

```
@(

  Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar()
                .DefaultGroup(group => group
                .Add("telerik.common.css")
                .Add("telerik.black.css").Combined(true).Compress(true)
                .Add("telerik." + "SELECTED ITEM FROM COMBOBOX.TEXT HERE"  + ".css", ).Combined(true).Compress(true)
                //.Add("telerik." + Html.GetCurrentTheme() + ".css").Combined(true).Compress(true)


                //"javascript:cbxTheme_onChange()"
                ))
```

Where it says "Selected Item from combobox.text here" the javascript function should be placing a string (which contains the name of the telerik style sheet to use. It should be working but it is not.

I even tried to address the combo box directly by saying:

```
 .Add("telerik." + cbxTheme.SelectedItem.text  + ".css", ).Combined(true).Compress(true)
```

which is how it is done on their site. But again it doesnt work.

Any help with this would be much appreicated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added an example of what you could do in the javascript function cbxTheme_onChange().

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks Daniel, I ahve accepted your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way Telerik does this on the demo site is by reloading the page and getting the theme from the querystring. Selecting a theme in the dropdown causes the page to be loaded with a url like this:

```
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/[control]?theme=[theme]
```

For example, in the tab strip examples, choosing the theme forest has this url.

```
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/tabstrip?theme=forest
```

The _Layout.cshtml file has this line (like you mentioned).

```
.Add("telerik." + Html.GetCurrentTheme() + ".css")
```

The Html.GetCurrentTheme() calls an extension method that gets the theme name from the querystring.

```
public static string GetCurrentTheme(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    return html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["theme"] ?? "vista";
}
```

If you wanted to use your javascript cbxTheme_onChange() function, you could do something similar to the Telerik demo page by reloading the page with a url that has a querystring with the name of the theme and then using that to set the style.

Add the window.location.href to your javascript function cbxTheme_onChange().

```
<script>
  function cbxTheme_onChange() {
    var selectedItemValue = $("#cbxTheme").data("tComboBox").value();
    window.location.href = window.location.protocol + '//' 
      + window.location.host + window.location.pathname 
      + '?theme=' + selectedItemValue;
  }
</script>
```